# SVG Appending/Creation with Byte Array in Golang

Tags: go, svg

I have an Image with its height, width and parameters. The objective is to create a file with pngs/jpgs into SVG. This SVG has to be portable without any additional files. When I tried with the approach mentioned in the SVGO documentation (code below), the svg takes a link reference to the Image. So when the image is deleted, svg will not have the Image in it. How do I push Image's byte[] into the SVG so that it becomes portable?
I have tried the below code.

```
func createSvgFromImage(ImageObjectStructures []ImageObjectStructure, filename string) {
    filename += ".svg"
    file, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("svg file creation error:", err)
    }
    width := int(10000)  // Has to be taken from individual page size
    height := int(10000) // Has to be taken from individual page size
    svg := svg.New(file)
    svg.Start(width, height)
    for i := 0; i < len(ImageObjectStructures); i++ {
        svg.Image(ImageObjectStructures[i].XPosition, ImageObjectStructures[i].YPosition, ImageObjectStructures[i].Width, ImageObjectStructures[i].Height, ImageObjectStructures[i].ImagePath, ImageObjectStructures[i].ImageCaption)
        file.Write(ImageObjectStructures[i].ImageData)
    }
    svg.End()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To embed the image data in the SVG, you'll need to use a Data URL.  You Base64-encode the image file data, then append it to a prefix string containing the URL scheme `data:`, the MIME type (eg. `image/png`) and the encoding (`base64`).

The SVG will end up looking like the following:

```
<svg ...>

  <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDo...etc..."/>

</svg>
```

You can [learn more about Data URLs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: This works when I am handling svg's directly. I am looking for code to do the same via Go Lang.

Comment: @RakhuNathan the solution is there. It should not be difficult to write the code yourself.